# How can I put two different variables inside of a textview in recyclerview when it runs a second time?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have one recyclierview adapter in my project. It loads two times and puts variables inside textview in activity. I want it to load different for the second time when it loads.

I just tried to make if clause for it. I wanted to make it will work else statement for first time adapter load. And I put "1" inside of i so, second time if i equals "1" it will work inside of if. But, when it loads the second time it is `default` value of `i`.

```
public class VoyageInformationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private String i;

                    if (i == "1"){
                        viewHolderBus.textV_from_city.setText(leg.getTo_city());
                        viewHolderBus.textV_to_city.setText(leg.getFrom_city());
                    }else{
                    viewHolderBus.textV_from_city.setText(leg.getFrom_city());
                    viewHolderBus.textV_to_city.setText(leg.getTo_city());
                    i = "1";
                   }}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't compare Strings with `==`, use `i.equals("1")`

Comment: @Kilarn123 The problem is it make equals i with "1". But when in second time it change with default value of "i".

Comment: Where do you call this code? in your `onBindViewHolder()` method?

Comment: @bautista this code inside of it. Should I put more code from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code would work for you

```
public class VoyageInformationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private String i;

                    if (i != null && i.equals("1")){
                        viewHolderBus.textV_from_city.setText(leg.getTo_city());
                        viewHolderBus.textV_to_city.setText(leg.getFrom_city());
                    }else{
                    viewHolderBus.textV_from_city.setText(leg.getFrom_city());
                    viewHolderBus.textV_to_city.setText(leg.getTo_city());
                    i = "1";
                   }}
```

Comment: The problem is it make equals i with `"1"`. But when in second time it change with default value of `"i"`.

Comment: I just did `public String i = 0;`. And, put your `i.equals("1")`. That work.